# OpsWorks Stack - Load-based instances scaling UP and DOWN based on cloudwatch alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks, amazon-cloudwatch

We have an opsworks stack with two 24x7 instances. Four time-based instances. Two load-based instances.

Our issue is with the load-based instances. We've spent a great deal of time creating meaningful-to-our-service cloudwatch alarms. Thus, we want the load-based instances in our stack to come UP when a particular cloudwatch latency alarm is in an ALARM state. I see that in the load-based instance configuration, you can define a cloudwatch alarm for bringing the instance(s) UP and you can define a cloudwatch alarm for bringing the instance(s) DOWN.

Thing is, when I select the specific cloudwatch alarm I want to use to trigger the UP, it removes that cloudwatch alarm from being selected as the trigger for DOWN. Why?

Specifically, we want our latency alarm (we'll call it the "oh crap things are slowing down" cloudwatch alarm) to trigger the load-based instances to START when in an ALARM state. Then, we want the "oh crap things are slowing down" cloudwatch alarm to trigger the load-based instances to SHUTDOWN when in an OK state. It would be rad if the load-based instances waited 15 minutes after the OK state of the alarm before shutting down.

The "oh crap things are slowing down" threshold is Latency > 2 for 3 minutes

Do I just need to create a new "oh nice things are ok" alarm with a threshold of Latency < 2 for 3 minutes to use as the DOWN alarm in the load-based instance configuration?

Sorry for the newbie question, just feel stuck.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you have to add a second alarm that triggers only when the latency is below 2 for three minutes. If someone else comes up with a cleaner solution than this, I'd love to hear about it. As it is, you'll always have one of the alerts in a continuous state of alarm.